# Как вывести картинку вложения в теле письма в верстке?

Tags: html, css, php

Подскажите, я делаю вложение файла и хотел бы, чтобы этот файл-картинка была позиционирована версткой внизу письма, подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: А как вы "делаете вложение" можно поинтересоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Если это html то используйте css:

```
<img src="..." style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px;">
```